# Clustering webservices over VPN

Tags: web-services, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, vpn, high-availability

We have number of web services exposed over VPN to our partners for their consumption. I was wondering, what would be the best way to make those web services highly available and scalabe for their usage. One option could be an apache sitting between our web services acting like a reverse proxy. But, that would introduce a single point of failure too. Can we use physical load balancer? I was not able to find any useful resources for planning out this activity. Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I did not work with physical load balancer, but Apache is a valid solution in most of the scenarios.
All of our clients (with critical back-end system) uses apache as a load balancer without problemas.
Most of the Application Servers also provide their custom integration with apache, like mod_jk for Weblogic or mod_cluster for JBoss.